# Identify dependencies among crm 2011 solutions

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to create a milestone solution containing all customizations(several  unmanaged crm solutions) in the past 3 months for deployment.

we need a full milestone solution, not the patch-on-patch way.Unfortunately, I am not sure the dependencies among these customizations.

1. How can I to identify dependencies among crm 2011 solutions?
2. Are there any tools that can do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

CRM 2011 has a built in dependency checker which can be used for each solution individually. You could start combining the solutions and adding the dependencies by clicking on the dependencies button in the Solution.

You could also programmatically add all dependency solutions:

> [Solutions are made of solution components. You’ll use the Solutions area in Microsoft Dynamics CRM to create or add solution components. You can perform these actions programmatically by using the AddSolutionComponentRequest message or any messages that create or update solution components that include a SolutionUniqueName parameter.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309749.aspx)

That is depending on how deep you want to get into the process.

Comment: yes. maybe it need to look into solution related tables in crm DB.